# Visual Studio 2017 registers 170k+ changes when trying to commit

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a problem, a serious one, and google didn't help me.

All of my solutions are stored at `C:\Users\UserName\source\repos`. Whenever I open a solution, and I want to commit my code, to use git, it registers every change made in the `C:\Users\UserName` . That is 170k+ changes. This problem is making my IDE really slow. How can I solve this?

Comment: I lost more than 6 hours of my life trying to fix this. You have my eternal gratitude.

Comment: @jessehouwing Write it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `.git` folder in your user profile directory so that folder is no longer the root of a git repository. That should get you out of this problem.